# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table movie

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I've a spring boot application which run sql on H2 to create database table during startup.
The project is in [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/spring-grpc-gradle-demo) here.

I've Entity called [Movie.java](https://github.com/rajcspsg/spring-grpc-gradle-demo/blob/main/movie-service/src/main/java/com/grpcflix/movie/entity/Movie.java)

The sql that I'm running is below and on [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/spring-grpc-gradle-demo/blob/main/movie-service/src/main/resources/data.sql) here -

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "movie";
CREATE TABLE "movie" AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('classpath:movie.csv');
```

The csv file that I'm inserting is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/spring-grpc-gradle-demo/blob/main/movie-service/src/main/resources/movie.csv)

```
id,title,year,rating,genre
1,The Shawshank Redemption,1994,9.3,DRAMA
2,The godfather,1972,9.2,DRAMA
3,Pulp Fiction,1994,8.9,CRIME
4,The good the bad and the ugly,1966,8.8,WESTERN
5,Inception,2010,8.8,ACTION
6,Se7en,1995,8.6,CRIME
7,City of god,2002,8.06,CRIME
8,Django unchained,2012,8.4,WESTERN
9,Oldboy,2003,8.4,ACTION
```

When I run the spring [application](https://github.com/rajcspsg/spring-grpc-gradle-demo/blob/main/movie-service/src/main/java/com/grpcflix/movie/MovieApplication.java) I get below error -

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table movie (id integer not null, genre varchar(255), rating double not null, title varchar(255), year integer not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:442) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
> at com.grpcflix.movie.MovieApplication.main(MovieApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table movie (id integer not null, genre varchar(255), rating double not null, title varchar(255), [*]year integer not null, primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
> create table movie (id integer not null, genre varchar(255), rating double not null, title varchar(255), year integer not null, primary key (id)) [42001-210]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:521) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:265) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5759) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseTableColumnDefinition(Parser.java:9355) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:9298) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table movie (id integer not null, genre varchar(255), rating double not null, title varchar(255), [*]year integer not null, primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
>
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6779) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:746) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:674) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:644) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:551) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:615) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:553) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar:2.1.210]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> ... 33 common frames omitted

I think the error is columns are in different order than it is defined in the entity from the SQL to create table.

```
create table movie (id integer not null, genre varchar(255), rating double not null, title varchar(255), [*]year integer not null, primary key (id))
```

Any idea how to ix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is probably `"movie"` as table-name incl the `"`

So this should work

**schema.sql**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie;
CREATE TABLE movie AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('classpath:movie.csv');
```

here is a working basic example:
[example on github](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/h2-create-table-from-csv)

Note for the example

- `schema.sql` for initialization of the DB [howto.data-initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)
- `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to disable Hibernate automatic schema creation